# I got an syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this JavaScript code

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => { return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, however IE gives me an syntax error pointing at => in my code.

Is there a way to use ES6 arrow syntax in IE?

Comment: IE Does not Support ES6

Comment: Could you help me to transform this code to the javascript regular one?

Comment: *Is there a way to use ES6 arrow syntax in IE?* you can use a pre-compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Though this wil just turn the arrow function into a standard function call and a `var _this = this` object, which is basically the same thing

Comment: Your not using scope so there is no reason to use an arrow function here, so you can re-write it simply: `var numberWithCommas = function(x) {....}`

Comment: Just change `(x) => ` to `function(x)`

Comment: Since I'm not good at javascript, and this bunch of code need to be fixed urgently, could you assist me with the code mentioned upper?

Comment: @Liam Thanks a lot, works perfect. Great assist :)

Comment: The [babel website](https://babeljs.io/) will do this for you too. type your code into the textbox